# How to get the port number alone using regex in c#?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

can anyone pls guide me to get the port number alone from the below line? Note: i have maintain this whole line as string.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\WebDev.WebServer40.EXE" /port:4274 /path:"F:\Program Files (x86)\Samples\test\" /vpath:"/"
```

Output i expected is 4274 alone.

I have tried many solutions from stackoverflow. nothing helps.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Karthi

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the below regex to get the number which exists next to the `port:` substring.

```
@"(?<=\bport\s*:\s*)\d+"
```

Comment: Thank you somuch @Avinash Raj

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# code without regex to obtain the number:

```
var val = string.Empty;
var port_num = inpt.Split(' ').
     Where(p => p.StartsWith("/port:")).FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(port_num))
     val = port_num.Substring(port_num.IndexOf(':')+1);
```

Output:

[image]